# Return a value of first & last row matching criterion in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 columns of numbers, the idea is to find the first & last value in column L that respects a criterion and return the value from the same row in column K.
As the criterion is "higher than 99% of the max value in column L", I tried the MINIFS formula, but I cannot use this as a criterion.

I guess the solution will include the MATCH, INDEX formula but I cannot find the right combination

In this specific example,  we want to return the value of the first column that has in column L a number higher than `0,99*max(L3:L62)`(=3.0879...) so it should return 19
This will be verified for a couple rows until the value goes below the 99% again. This last row is 58.

**Link to sheet** :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MUkYDPoR1NxB8qWcYr_2Fp91FgUbnUOpfGd7EUuWCOg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share the sheet so we can test potential solutions?

Comment: People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: sure, I just did it sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try the following:

For first value

```
=Index(K3:K62;Min(IFERROR(1/(1/((Row(K3:K62)*(L3:L62>0,99*max(L3:L62)))))))-2)
```

For last value

```
=Index(K3:K62;Max(IFERROR(1/(1/((Row(K3:K62)*(L3:L62>0,99*max(L3:L62)))))))-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=query({K3:L62};"select Col1 where Col2 > "&substitute(to_text(0,99*MAX(L3:L62));",";".")&" limit 1";0)
```

query as app script needs US notation in values (dot instead of comma)

to get the last row

```
=query({K3:L62};"select Col1 where Col2 > "&SUBSTITUTE(to_text(0,99*MAX(L3:L62));",";".")&" order by Col1 desc limit 1";0)
```

Comment: Indeed it works. It's very complicated though. I saw that you found another way too : `=1+EQUIV(0,99*max(L3:L62);L3:L62)` which seems a bit lighter even though I'm not sure why it works. What do you think the best way is ? Taking into account I'll need to perform the same thing to return the last row where value is above 99%

Comment: I have added the formula for the last row, i am not sure to find another solution with equiv/match. query is very powerfull and simple (here the difficulty is to transform the max value in us notation).

Comment: Both answers work great really, I'm not experienced enough to tell if one is better than the other, I just find the other one easier to understand. Thanks a lot for your time, it's good to have 2 different approaches

Comment: Good ! as far as i am concerned, i have to admit that i have more difficulties to understand the other solution, it is why i have given the complete list of row that fit the criteria. Have a good day !